# Kohana Framework: add default option

Tags: php, orm, frameworks, rad, kohana-3

```
<?php
// My controller.
$marcas = ORM::Factory('marca')->
find_all()->
as_array('nome', 'nome');
array_unshift($marcas, '-- Selecione --');
?>

<?php
// My view.
echo Form::select('marca', $marcas, '-- Selecione --')
?>
```

Is there a faster way to add a default option in a select?
Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason for '-- Selecione --' param in `Form::select()`? You should use array keys instead of values: `Form::select('marca', $marcas, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Your way looks pretty fast and elegant, using the existing framework functionality with some smart data to take advantage of it.

You could probably extend Form::select() with your own code if you want to have any customized behaviour not outright supported. I know Kohana strongly suggests extending its core classes, that but I haven't played with Kohana3 yet. In Kohana2 you'd do it [as seen here](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/libraries#extending_libraries). According to [this tutorial](http://www.danhulton.com/blog/2010/07/07/stupidly-useful-kohana-3-tricks-safely-extending-base-classes/) for Kohana3 you'd do it similarly, but placing your new file in the application/classes folder.

A wild stab at guessing how this would work: create form.php in application/classes and enter:

```
class Form extends Form_Core {

    public static function select() {
        /**
         * Add the code from http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana3-core/repository/revisions/master/entry/classes/kohana/form.php#L252
         * and change it slightly to also include a default value when writing out
         * the form, or even better via another optional function parameter
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful though if you're using the array key for the database value eg as a lookup field. Array_unshift will renumber your elements so you may prefer `Arr::unshift($marcas, '', '--Selecione--');`.The other advantage is that returns the array, so you can use within the function call params rather than as a separate line

Refer [Arr::unshift()](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Arr#unshift)

```
<?php echo Form::select('marcas', Arr::unshift($marcas, '', '--Selecione--') , false);?>
```